# How to set the value of a component to a number

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I use the value for 'first' on a repeat control to know where I was as

```
sessionScope.ssCat1First = getComponent("repeatCat1").first;
```

so I can set the Starting Index value to ssCat1First and I'm on the right page. However, under some conditions I need to reset first on the component

I tried

```
getComponent("repeatCat1").first.setValue(0);
```

but I get the error " Error calling method 'setValue(number)' on an object of type 'Number [JavaScript Object]'" 
So it looks like where I have 0 in need a Java Object? If so how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a list of all properties and methods of Xsp components from [JavaDoc Package com.ibm.xsp.component.xp](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/DesignerAPIs/com/ibm/xsp/component/xp/package-summary.html).

How you can find the control's component class? Just print the object's class name to servers console with a button. For your **repeat control** example you'd write:

```
<xp:button
    value="Show class"
    id="button2">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print(getComponent("repeatCat1"))}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

and console will show you something like
`HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspDataIterator@20f620f6`.

Now, look for class `XspDataIterator` in JavaDoc. This class doesn't have a method `getFirst()` or `setFirst()` but the parent class `com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator` has:

[image]

Keep in mind that `getComponent("repeatCat1").first` is the Expression Language version of `getComponent("repeatCat1").getFirst()`. That's what really gets executed.

The same applies to a **pager**. You'd look for XspPager and then for parents class com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager. There you can see how to set the page number for a pager:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use setFirst():

```
getComponent("repeatCat1").setFirst(0);
```

Comment: Thanks - is there a place where one can get a list of the properties and methods for various components. For example I need to set the page number for a pager